# AttributeError using Python in Replit

Tags: python

Trying to do a project by making a game of Blackjack but I keep getting AttributeError and unable to determined if I misspelled something or if I forgot to add something.

```
import random
import os

#Class function for cards
class Card:
  def __init__(self, suit, value, card_value):

    #Suit for a Card like Clubs
    self.suit = suit

    #Value of a Card like A for Ace
    self.value = value

    #Number value of a Card like King = 10
    self.card_value = card_value

#Clear console funtion to clear console screen
def clear():
  os.system("clear")


#Allow design of card to be made
def print_cards(card, hidden):

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t __________"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t __________"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |        |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    if card.value == '10':
      s = s + "\t | {}        |".format(card.value)
    else:
      s = s + "\t | {}        |".format(card.value)
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |        |"
    print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |         |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |  * *   |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t | *   *  |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t | *   *  |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |   {}    |".format(card.suit)
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |   *    |"
  print (s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |   *    |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |   *    |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |        |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |        |"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |        |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    if card.value == "10":
      s = s + "\t |       {} |".format(card.value)
    else:
      s = s + "\t |       {} |".format(card)
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |   *    |"
  print(s)

  s = ""
  for card in cards:
    s = s + "\t |________|"
  if hidden:
    s += "\t |________|"
  print(s)

  print()

#Start function for a game of Blackjack
def blackjack_game(deck):

  #Card hands to be given to both player and dealer
  player_cards = []
  dealer_cards = []
  
  #Score for both player and dealer equal to the cards they have
  player_score = 0
  dealer_score = 0

  clear()

  #Start for dealing cards to player and dealer
  while len(player_cards) < 2:

    #Deal random cards to player
    player_card = random.choice(deck)
    player_cards.append(player_card)
    deck.remove(player_card)

    #Update player score
    player_score += player_card.card_value

    #If player has 2 Aces
    if len(player_cards) == 2:
      if player_card[0].card_value == 11 and player_cards[1].card_value == 11:
        player_cards[0].card_value == 1
        player_score -= 10

    #Print players cards and score
    print("Player Cards: ")
    print_cards(player_cards, False)
    print("Player Score = ", player_score)

    input()

    #Deal random cards to dealer
    dealer_card = random.choice(deck)
    dealer_cards.append(dealer_card)
    deck.remove(dealer_card)

    #Update dealer score
    dealer_score += dealer_card.card_value

    #Print dealer's first card and hide second card from player
    print("Dealer Cards: ")
    if len(dealer_cards) == 1:
      print_cards(dealer_cards, False)
      print("Dealer Score = ", dealer_score)
    else:
        print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)
        print("Dealer Score = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)

    #If dealer has 2 Aces
    if len(dealer_cards) == 2:
      if dealer_card[0].card_value == 11 and dealer_cards[1].card_value == 11:
        dealer_cards[0].card_value == 1
        dealer_score -= 10

    input()
        
  #If player gets blackjack
  if player_score == 21:
    print("Player has Blackjack!")
    print("Player Wins!")
    quit()

  clear()


  #Print Dealer Cards and score
  print("Dealer Cards: ")
  print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)
  print("Dealer Score = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)

  print()

  #Print Player Cards and score
  print("Player Cards: ")
  print_cards(player_cards, False)
  print("Player Score = ", player_score)

  #While Loop  to allow user to make an input to Hit or Stand while under 21
  while player_score < 21:
    choice = input("Press H to Hit or S to Stand : ")

    #Check to make sure user is putting in a correct input
    if len(choice) != 1 or (choice.upper() != "H" and choice.upper() != "S"):
      clear()
      print("Please choose either H for Hit or S for Stand")
      
    #If player hits
    if choice.upper() == "H":

      #Deal another card to player
      player_card = random.choice(deck)
      player_cards.append(player_card)
      deck.remove(player_card)

      #Update players score
      player_score += player_card.card_value

      #Check and update score to see if they have an Ace and over 21
      c = 0
      while player_score > 21 and c < len(player_cards):
        if player_cards[c].card_value == 11:
          player_cards[c].card_value = 1
          player_score -= 10
          c += 1
        else:
          c += 1

      #Clear console
      clear()

      #Print Dealer Cards and score
      print("Dealer Cards: ")
      print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)
      print("Dealer Score = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)
    
      print()
    
      #Print Player Cards and score
      print("Player Cards: ")
      print_cards(player_cards, False)
      print("Player Score = ", player_score)

    #If player stands
    if choice.upper() == "S":
      break

    #Continue to dealer's turn

  #Clear Console
  clear()

  #While loop if dealer score is less than 17
  while dealer_score < 17:
    clear()

    #print when deal hits
    print("Dealer is going to Hit.")

    #Dealing cards to dealer
    dealer_card = random.choice(deck)
    dealer_cards.append(dealer_card)
    deck.remove(dealer_card)

    #Update Dealer score
    dealer_score += dealer_card.card_value

    #Check and update score to see if they have an Ace and over 21
    c = 0
    while dealer_score > 21 and c < len(dealer_cards):
      if dealer_cards[c].card_value == 11:
        dealer_cards[c].card_value = 1
        dealer_score -= 10
        c += 1
      else:
        c += 1

    #Print Dealer Cards and score
    print("Dealer Cards: ")
    print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)
    print("Dealer Score = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)
  
    print()
  
    #Print Player Cards and score
    print("Player Cards: ")
    print_cards(player_cards, False)
    print("Player Score = ", player_score)

    input()

  clear()

  #Show dealers hand
  print("Dealer will now show their hand.")
  print()
  print("Dealers Cards: ")
  print_cards(dealer_cards, False)
  print("Dealer Score = ", dealer_score)

  #Show player hand
  print("Player Cards: ")
  print_cards(player_cards, False)
  print("Player Score = ", player_score)

  #If dealer busts
  if dealer_score > 21:
    print ("Dealer busts, Player Wins!")
    quit()
  
  #If dealer gets blackjack(21)
  if dealer_score == 21:
    print("Dealer has Blackjack, Player loses.")
    quit()
  
  #If tie happened
  if dealer_score == player_score:
    print("Score is tied.")
  
  #Elif player wins
  elif player_score > dealer_score:
    print("Player Wins!")
  
  #Else dealer wins
  else:
    print("Dealer Wins!")

#Funtion for the deck
if __name__ == "__main__":

  #Type of suits
  suits = ["Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"]

  #Symbols for suits
  suits_values = {"Clubs":"\u2667", "Diamonds":"\u2662", "Hearts":"\u2661", "Spades":"\u2664" }
  
  #Type of card 
  cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
  
  #Value of Card
  cards_values = {"A":11, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10, "J":10, "Q":10,"K":10}
  
  #Creating a Deck variable for the cards
  deck = []
  
  #A loop for the suits of card 
  for suit in suits:
    
    #A loop for the type of card in suit
    for card in cards:
  
      #Adding card to deck
      deck.append(Card(suits_values[suit], card, cards_values[card]))
      
  #Call for blackjack game function
  blackjack_game(deck)
```

Error with the code I got.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 364, in <module>
    blackjack_game(deck)
  File "main.py", line 156, in blackjack_game
    print_cards(player_cards, False)
  File "main.py", line 41, in print_cards
    if card.value == '10':
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I've already tried to see if some sort of online source to see if I could find so sort of answer but anything I found either I didn't understand or didn't help me find.

Comment: You should try to print the `cards` variable in the `print_cards` function and see what you got

Comment: Oh ! Your parameter is named `card` in the `print_cards` function, it should be `cards`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your     `card` input for the     `print_cards` function should be
`cards` instead of     `card` in order for the for loop to identify it correctly. As for the error, I think what you mean on line 41 after the correction suggested above is:
`card.card_value == '10'`
because the    `card` being referenced in the     `print_cards` function is an instance of the Card class and its value is being held in the     `card_value` variable.